# Nullify some properties when getting the response from a method - Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the bellow apis in my application. My application manages spring security and in the logic there are some rules like based on the user's role , the user might be able to see or not certain attributes.
So my requirement it is to make null some attributes of the CustomObject based on the user's role.
Is there a way to accomplish this based with Spring Security ? There is the @PostFilter annotation but I think it will be useful to discard objects in the method's response , but not to make some attributes of the object null

```
public List<CustomObject> getCustomObjects() 
public CustomObject getCustomObject()
```

If this is not possible with only spring security, I am thinking to create a custom annotation , mixed with some AOP to do the work, what do you think ?